# Change -webkit-tap-highlight-color to transparent

Tags: css, iphone

I've added the -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); to my CSS on the following website: http://www.aanzet.eu

Still on the iphone the problem occurs with a flashing pink color when I click on links.

Have search StackExchange but didn't find a solution for my problem. Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Try [these instructions](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-gray-highlight-when-tapping-links-in-mobile-safari/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try both selectors:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

Comment: By adding your code and the following code the problem was solved:

document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);